# Bootstrapper, Sync Framework 2.1 - Prerequisites

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-sync-framework, bootstrapper, prerequisites

**EDIT:** After even more searching I found a way to complete this.
I used [This preview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee726596.aspx) to alter my Product.xml
then I copied some of my existing Product.xml to Check if it is installed already.

So I successfully implemented the Sync Framework 2.1 on my system and in my C# Application. However when I publish it and test it on another pc where Sync Framework is not installed, it comes up with errors
So I try to include the SyncSDK-v2.1-x86-ENU.msi on install.

After searching I found out that I need to add it to the prerequisites list (Project -> Properties -> Publish -> prerequisites)

I've tried following this link about [Creating Custom Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.100).aspx). However it still points to the BMG (Bootstrapper Manifest Generator) file which does not exists anymore.

Next solution was to create it manually, I think I'm on the right path but just can't complete it. What I did:

- Downloaded dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe and put it into: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX45
- Made a new folder called SyncFrame inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
- Added a Product.xml and copied the SyncSDK-v2.1-x86-ENU.msi to the SyncFrame folder. Also added a  subfolder "en", in there made a Package.xml and a Eula.rtf file.
- In VS2013, Project->Properties->Publish->Prerequisites I've chosen "Download prerequisites from same the location as my application".
- When published, it successfully adds a 'dotnetfx45' folder to the published folder containing the .exe file. This ofcourse because I checked "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64) in the Prerequisites selection box.

However I still can't manage to get the Sync Framework 2.1 into the Prerequisites selection box.

Here is my (probably rubbish) Product.xml:
**EDIT:** This is now Product.xml that fixed my problem:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Product
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
 ProductCode="Microsoft.Sample.EULA">
 <!-- Defines the list of files to be copied on build. -->
<PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
<PackageFile Name="SyncSDK-v2.1-x86-ENU.msi"/>
 </PackageFiles>

<InstallChecks>
  <MsiProductCheck Product="IsMsiInstalled"
   Property="{{4A3EAF2F-F950-4BF2-B0C7-857E0E970E5A}}"/>
 </InstallChecks>

<!-- Defines how to run the Setup package.-->
 <Commands >
  <Command PackageFile = "SyncSDK-v2.1-x86-ENU.msi" Arguments=''>
   <InstallConditions>
    <BypassIf Property="IsMsiInstalled"
      Compare="ValueGreaterThan" Value="0"/>
    <FailIf Property="AdminUser"
      Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="True"
     String="NotAnAdmin"/>
  </InstallConditions>
  <ExitCodes>
    <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
    <ExitCode Value="-1" Result="Fail" String="AU_Unaccepted" />
    <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" 
      FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
  </ExitCodes>
  </Command>
</Commands>
```

I've used [How to create Product Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee335701(v=vs.100).aspx) to make this...

And here is my Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Package
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
 Name="DisplayName"
 Culture="Culture"
  LicenseAgreement="Eula.rtf">

  <PackageFiles>
<PackageFile Name="Eula.rtf"/>
 </PackageFiles>

  <Strings>
<String Name="DisplayName">Sync Framework 2.1</String>
<String Name="Culture">en</String>
<String Name="NotAnAdmin">You must be an administrator to install this package.       </String>
  <String Name="GeneralFailure">
  A general error has occurred while
  installing this package.
   </String>
  </Strings>
 </Package>
```

A little side question but not the problem at all at the moment, I also make use of SQL databases, locally included in the project and online databases, Do I need to select more Prerequisites in the Prerequisites selection box. like SQL server express 2012 localDB?
**Edit:** Yes

This works ok, but I would still like to create a product.xml so it automatically downloads from the website instead of putting it within the install folder. It kind of makes the install folder to big for a small app.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I finished the bootstrapper based on bootstrappers for sync framework 2.0

here is the package and product xml respectively:

product.xml for SyncFX20Core(x64)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="SyncFX20Core(x64)"/>
```

package.xml for SyncFX20Core(x64)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package Name="DisplayName" LicenseAgreement="synchronizationeula_english.rtf" Culture="Culture" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="synchronizationeula_english.rtf" />
    <PackageFile Name="Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi" HomeSite="SyncFX21_64" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi" Arguments="/quiet" EstimatedInstallSeconds="80" EstimatedTempBytes="20000000">
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
        <ExitCode Value="112" Result="Fail" String="DiskFull" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
  <Strings>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
    <String Name="DisplayName">SyncFX21Core (x64)</String>
    <String Name="SyncFX21_64">http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/E/E1E636E6-AA5C-4052-9927-D722312DB564/Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi</String>
    <String Name="DiskFull">DiskFull</String>
    <String Name="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
  </Strings>
</Package>
```

product.xml for SyncFX20DatabaseProviders(x64)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="SyncFX20DatabaseProviders(x64)" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <RelatedProducts>
    <DependsOnProduct Code="SyncFX20Core(x64)" />
  </RelatedProducts>
</Product>
```

package for for SyncFX20DatabaseProviders(x64)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package Name="DisplayName" LicenseAgreement="databaseproviderseula_english.rtf" Culture="Culture" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="databaseproviderseula_english.rtf" />
    <PackageFile Name="DatabaseProviders-v3.1-x64-ENU.msi" HomeSite="SyncFX21DatabaseProviders_64" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="DatabaseProviders-v3.1-x64-ENU.msi" Arguments="/quiet" EstimatedInstallSeconds="80" EstimatedTempBytes="20000000">
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
        <ExitCode Value="112" Result="Fail" String="DiskFull" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
  <Strings>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
    <String Name="DisplayName">SyncFX21DatabaseProviders (x64)</String>
    <String Name="SyncFX21DatabaseProviders_64">http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/E/E1E636E6-AA5C-4052-9927-D722312DB564/DatabaseProviders-v3.1-x64-ENU.msi</String>
    <String Name="DiskFull">DiskFull</String>
    <String Name="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
  </Strings>
</Package>
```

Please Feel free to contact me if you need more details or the source files... ameser@gmail.com

Cheers!.

Comment: feel free to contact me @RageCompex if you need help

Comment: When I intent to use it again I will, but for now I'm pretty busy with other projects. What I do notice is that you are saying it is Sync Version 2.0, but in the first package.xml it downloads `Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi`. If I am correct, I'm not sure. Probably good job though

Comment: This is confusing as hell. There is the SDK that is different from Synchornization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi

Answer (score 0):

Xml for x86 version with Installed check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="SyncFX21Core (x86)" >
    <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
        <PackageFile Name="synchronization-v2.1-x86-enu.msi" PublicKey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
    </PackageFiles>

    <InstallChecks>
        <RegistryCheck Property="Installed" Key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Sync Framework\v2.1\Setup\SynchronizationX86" Value="Install"/>
    </InstallChecks>

    <Commands>
        <Command PackageFile="synchronization-v2.1-x86-enu.msi" Arguments="/quiet" EstimatedInstallSeconds="80" EstimatedTempBytes="20000000">
            <InstallConditions>
                <BypassIf Property="Installed" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="1" />
                <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
            </InstallConditions>
            <ExitCodes>
                <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
                <ExitCode Value="112" Result="Fail" String="DiskFull" />
                <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
            </ExitCodes>
        </Command>
    </Commands>
    <Strings>
        <String Name="DiskFull">DiskFull</String>
        <String Name="AdminRequired">Administrator permissions are required to install Sync Framework 2.1. Contact your administrator.</String>    
        <String Name="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
    </Strings>
</Product>
```