# microsoft synchronization data server version 2.0.0.0 to be installed in Global Assembly cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to deploy my published project in a client's computer but the setup keeps giving me this error "microsoft synchronization data server version 2.0.0.0 to be installed in Global Assembly cache" first

Any help with that would be appreciated!
I worked on C# Visual stuido 2010 and my PC is 64bit, and my clients pc is also 64bit
Thanks

Comment: have you installed Sync Framework? On your clients pc

Comment: no I haven't from where can I install it? as my client doesn't have visual studio or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install Sync Framework on your clients PC. Maybe some other Sql frameworks as well.

[This page says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937137%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> On an x86 platform, the x86 installation package installs the
>   following components into Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Sync
>   Framework\2.1, and adds managed DLLs to the global assembly cache
>   (GAC). On an x64 platform, both the x86 and the x64 installation
>   package install into Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Sync
>   Framework\2.1. Other combinations of platform and installation package
>   may yield slight variations on the installation path.

[Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217)

if you would like to have this as prerequisites when installing the application, look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331096/bootstrapper-sync-framework-2-1-prerequisites).
However I advise you to use Inno Script studio to make installers. (Free and easy to use, but I guess it is not that hard to reverse engineer, just saying).

[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752882/how-can-i-install-net-framework-as-a-prerequisite-using-innosetup/20753218?noredirect=1#comment43680248_20753218) about getting .NET framework 4.0 (or any other) installed automatically with Inno Script.

When you have done that, here is how I managed to install Sync Framework as well, not fully automatic yet but it at least launches the installer when installing your app. and goes trough the setup well, I couldn't get it done automatically because Sync Framework installer is a `.MSI` file.

Add this to file section:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:DIRECTORYHERE\Dependencies\SqlLocalDB.MSI"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Permissions: everyone-full; Check: SqlIsNotInstalled; AfterInstall: InstallSql
```

Code section (you can just place this at the bottom of the script):

```
[Code]
procedure InstallSql;

var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  StatusText: string;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing Microsoft SQL Local Database...';

   if not ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SqlLocalDB.MSI'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
     begin
    MsgBox('SQL local DB failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
      mbError, MB_OK);
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;

  end;
end;
```

And check if it is installed already or not:

```
[code]
function SqlIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\11.0');
end;
```

Comment: Actually what I did just now was I changed the setting of the files within the application files from prerequest(auto) to include and it worked, would it cause any problems in the future or it would work normally now?

Comment: O well if it is that easy then skip that thread of mine, for me I couldn't choose it from the list of Prerequisites. I think it won't have any problems in the future but I advice you use other software to make installers, ClickOnce apps are not that ... safe.

Comment: thanks for the instant reply and help, the app is for a single client so, no safety worries should I keep it as it is using the ClickOnce app or make a new installer for it?

Comment: Just looks more professional, no problem for keeping it as a ClickOnce app in that case.